How to open dialog with value calling ajax function
I m building an application using php 7.
So with the following code, I can populate the table using a JSON that I received from a specific class.
$.post("select_ordini.php",{dataInizio:dataInizio,dataFine:dataFine,suffissoTable:suffissoTable}, function(data){},"json").done(function(data) { 
                if(data!=null){
                    var PageViewDeterPiu = [];
                    var dataAttuale="";
                    $.each(data,function(i,item){
                        $('#tb-lezioni').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                          item.codOrdine,
                          item.data,
                          item.fatturaNro,
                          item.totaleOrdine
                        ]); 
                        
                    });
                    //var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
                    //dialog.showModal();
                    notification("Notifica","Caricamento terminato");
                }else{
                    notification("Notifica","Nessun Risultato trovato");
                }
                

            }).fail(function(){
                notification("Notifica","Caricamento non terminato");
            }).always(function() { });
                 
            });

This is the result:

Now I need to implement this behaviour, if I click on one element of my table (for me is ok also the ID column value), the web page open a Dialog with a tableB the value of a tableB must be get from a database by call "select_ordini_articoli.php" page.

This seems like something you would implement in your datatable settings. There should be be a way to specify a handler for clicking on a row.

That function can make an AJAX call to select_ordini_articoli.php

"PHP how open dialog with value calling ajax function" - that won't work, as PHP can't open any dialog. PHP runs on the server, while the dialog must be rendered through JS
